# R two plots overlay

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help with a plot in R.

I get a plot with a source "data_small".
I now have a second source "data_big" which I want to overlay in the same plot.

Both sources have the columns "risk_datatheft_likelihood" and "risk_datatheft_damage"

Any idea? the second source should be displayed in a different color.

```
ggplot(data_small, aes(risk_datatheft_likelihood, risk_datatheft_damage)) + 
  geom_jitter(color="blue") + 
  labs(x = "damage", y = "likelihood",
       title = "Risk Map", subtitle = "Datatheft") + 
        theme_classic() +
        theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, color="red") + 
        geom_hline(yintercept = 1.5) + 
        geom_hline(yintercept = 2.5) + 
        geom_hline(yintercept = 3.5) + 
        geom_hline(yintercept = 4.5) + 
        geom_vline(xintercept = 0.5, color="red") + 
        geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5) + 
        geom_vline(xintercept = 2.5) + 
        geom_vline(xintercept = 3.5) + 
        geom_vline(xintercept = 4.5)

data_big.csv
risk_datatheft_likelihood;risk_datatheft_damage
B;3
B;2
C;4
A;1
D;5

data_small.csv
risk_datatheft_likelihood;risk_datatheft_damage
C;4
A;2
B;3
C;4
D;1
```

Comment: please share the both of datasets

Comment: not here, to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably just want to bind the rows of the two datasets with a new variable to distinguish them, like so:

```
bind_rows(mutate(data_big, size="big"),
          mutate(data_small, size="small"))
```

This produces a tibble that looks like:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   risk_datatheft_likelihood risk_datatheft_damage size 
   <chr>                                     <int> <chr>
 1 B                                             3 big  
 2 B                                             2 big  
 3 C                                             4 big  
 4 A                                             1 big  
 5 D                                             5 big  
 6 C                                             4 small
 7 A                                             2 small
 8 B                                             3 small
 9 C                                             4 small
10 D                                             1 small
```

Now, you can use `size` as the color aesthetic:

```
bind_rows(mutate(data_big, size="big"),
          mutate(data_small, size="small")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(risk_datatheft_likelihood, risk_datatheft_damage)) +
    geom_jitter(aes(col=size))
```

Here's the full code followed by a transcript, since you were having trouble reproducing my solution.

The full code:

```
library(tidyverse)

data_big <- read_delim("data_big.csv", delim=";")
data_small <- read_delim("data_small.csv", delim=";")

# run the plot using one multiline command:
bind_rows(mutate(data_big, size="big"),
          mutate(data_small, size="small")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(risk_datatheft_likelihood, risk_datatheft_damage)) +
    geom_jitter(aes(col=size))

# alternatively, save the combined data first
data_combined <- bind_rows(mutate(data_big, size="big"),
                           mutate(data_small, size="small"))

# and run the plot separately
ggplot(data_combined,
       aes(risk_datatheft_likelihood, risk_datatheft_damage)) +
    geom_jitter(aes(col=size)) +
    labs(x = "damage", y = "likelihood",
         title = "Risk Map", subtitle = "Datatheft") +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position="bottom") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, color="red") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 2.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 3.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 4.5) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0.5, color="red") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 2.5) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 3.5) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 4.5)
```

and the complete transcript:

```
> library(tidyverse)
[... stuff about loading tidyverse ...]
> 
> data_big <- read_delim("data_big.csv", delim=";")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  risk_datatheft_likelihood = col_character(),
  risk_datatheft_damage = col_integer()
)
> data_small <- read_delim("data_small.csv", delim=";")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  risk_datatheft_likelihood = col_character(),
  risk_datatheft_damage = col_integer()
)
> 
> # run the plot using one multiline command:
> bind_rows(mutate(data_big, size="big"),
+           mutate(data_small, size="small")) %>%
+     ggplot(aes(risk_datatheft_likelihood, risk_datatheft_damage)) +
+     geom_jitter(aes(col=size))
> 
> # alternatively, save the combined data first
> data_combined <- bind_rows(mutate(data_big, size="big"),
+                            mutate(data_small, size="small"))
> 
> # and run the plot separately
> ggplot(data_combined,
+        aes(risk_datatheft_likelihood, risk_datatheft_damage)) +
+     geom_jitter(aes(col=size)) +
+     labs(x = "damage", y = "likelihood",
+          title = "Risk Map", subtitle = "Datatheft") +
+     theme_classic() +
+     theme(legend.position="bottom") +
+     geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, color="red") +
+     geom_hline(yintercept = 1.5) +
+     geom_hline(yintercept = 2.5) +
+     geom_hline(yintercept = 3.5) +
+     geom_hline(yintercept = 4.5) +
+     geom_vline(xintercept = 0.5, color="red") +
+     geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5) +
+     geom_vline(xintercept = 2.5) +
+     geom_vline(xintercept = 3.5) +
+     geom_vline(xintercept = 4.5)
>
```

Comment: now I get this error: Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?

Comment: Is it possible you missed the `%>%` operator at the end of `bind_rows`?  It sounds like R didn't pass the new data frame to `ggplot`, which would have happened if you ran `ggplot` on a line by itself without input from the `%>%` operator.  I've added a full transcript to my answer that includes an alternate solution, too, so maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your help!
I am not shure, but this cobination works also:

```
bind_rows(mutate(data_big, size="big"),
          mutate(data_small, size="small")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(risk_datatheft_likelihood, risk_datatheft_damage)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(col=size)) +
  labs(x = "risk_datatheft_likelihood", y = "risk_datatheft_damage",
       title = "Risk Map", subtitle = "Risiko: Datatheft") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, color="red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 2.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 4.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.5, color="red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 3.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 4.5)
```